# Is it necessary to append a comma before the coordinate conjunction "or" here?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, independent-clauses, compound-sentences

Here's my initial attempt at formulating this sentence in a grammatically correct manner:

> I can't tell if I should be insulted by this recommendation because of
> what I think the YouTube algorithm's reason is (you know what it is)
> or if I should be flattered because the video is about a highly
> academic topic.

I'm aware of the widely known general rule that for a comma to be required in a sentence, the sentence should be compound. I.e., it should have two or more independent clauses.

My problem now is ascertaining whether the second clause is in fact an independent clause.

Comment: There are two independent clauses, and they get a comma to separate them. You could make yourself crazy by saying there is one "I can't tell (**if** ... or **if**), but don't.

Comment: Punctuation is invariably a matter of *style*, which means there's no "grammatically correct" manner but merely a matter of convention, with which you are entitled to break. Do you think it reads better by giving the reader a signal to pause and take a breath after the first independent clause and parenthetical? I do. But that's just my opinion, as will be any other answer – and questions that encourage opinions are off-topic on this site. For further guidance, see [ask] and take our [Tour]. :-)

Comment: Lengthy though it is, your sentence boils down to this: "I can't tell if X or if Y." You don't need a comma after "X" in that construction.